# Espresso for tablayout and view pager inside relative how to perform click and swipe (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, android-espresso-recorder

I am try to testing my apps using espresso

when I try to swipe viewpager using:

```
onView(withId(view_pager)).perform(swipeRight())
```

I get error :
**Error performing 'fast swipe' on view**

cause I use tab layout and view pager I try to click the tab item inside the tabview, using like this :

```
onView(withId(tabItem)).perform(click())
```

and I get error :
**No views in hierarchy found matching**

I also try to use record Espresso test, end when I try to run with that I get error like the first.

my hierarchy XML layout look like:

```
<nested scroll>
        <relative>
            <linear>
                <tab layout>
                      <item1></item1>
                      <item2></item2>
                </tab layout>
                <view pager></view pager>
             </linear>
         </relative>
</nested>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get **Error performing 'action' on view** is because of your target view fails to match with one or more constraints. And in your case, you're trying to perform swipe action on `ViewPager`, and the action requires the view to display at least 90% on the screen. So it is very likely your `ViewPager` is too tall to meet the constraint, or no space to perform the action.

You should use [ViewPagerActions.scrollRight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/ViewPagerActions.html#scrollRight()) on `ViewPager` instead of [ViewActions.swipeRight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#swipeRight()). `ViewPagerActions.scrollRight` only checks if the view is partially displayed, and more reliable than `ViewActions.swipeRight`.

And if you get **No views in hierarchy found matching**, that means it can't find the view that you claim in `onView`, so it's either no such view or you're just on a wrong screen.

Comment: I've had similar problem above. But seem to still have 'No views in hierarchy found error' using scrollRight()